# Coerce the output of function markovchain::fitHigherOrder( ) to the same class as the output of markovchain::markovchainFit( )?

Tags: r, list, markov-chains

I'm working with the `markovchain` package in R to generate rudimentary sentences using Markov chains. I have successfully applied a function published on RPubs (Ref 1) named `create_me` to a text file of The Little Prince (Ref 2) to generate rudimentary sentences given a first word and a fitted Markov chain object. I've been using the `markovchainFit` function to train a first-order Markov chain, which works perfectly.

Here's the snippet for that:

```
    setwd(...)
    library(markovchain)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(textclean)
library(tokenizers)
set.seed(123)
tlp <- read.delim("tlp_transcription.txt", col.names = "text") #text file copied from Ref 2
tlp_clean <- tlp %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% # remove first line (version info)
  filter(!str_detect(text, "[/:]"), # remove lines with certain characters
         !str_detect(text, "Chapter")) # remove lines with certain string

tlp_clean  <- tlp_clean %>% 
  mutate(text = tolower(text) %>% # tolower sentences
           replace_contraction() %>%  # expand contraction
           replace_white() %>%  # replace double white space into single space
           str_remove_all(pattern = "lpp_1943.") %>% # remove pattern
           str_remove_all(pattern = "[0-9]") %>% # remove numbers
           str_remove_all(pattern = "[()]") %>% # remove specific punctuation
           str_remove_all(pattern = "--") %>%
           str_replace_all(pattern = " - ", replacement = "-") %>%  # replace pattern
           str_replace_all(pattern = "n't", replacement = "not") %>% 
           str_remove(pattern = "[.]") %>% # remove first matched pattern
           str_remove(pattern = " "))

# split words from sentences
text_tlp <- tlp_clean %>% 
  pull(text) %>% 
  strsplit(" ") %>% 
  unlist() 

fit_markov <- markovchainFit(text_tlp)
create_me <- function(num = 5, first_word = "i", n = 2) {
  for (i in 1:num) {
    set.seed(i+5)
    markovchainSequence(n = n, # generate 2 additional random words
                        markovchain = fit_markov$estimate,
                        t0 = tolower(first_word), include.t0 = T) %>% 
      # joint words
      paste(collapse = " ") %>% # join generated words with space
      # create proper sentence form
      str_replace_all(pattern = " ,", replacement = ",") %>% 
      str_replace_all(pattern = " [.]", replacement = ".") %>% 
      str_replace_all(pattern = " [!]", replacement = "!") %>% 
      str_to_sentence() %>% # start every sentences with capitalization
      print()
  }
}
create_me()
[1] "I saw the"
[1] "I were some"
[1] "I do not"
[1] "I was a"
[1] "I could fly"
```

However, I ran into problems when I trying to modify `create_me` to use the output of function `fitHigherOrder.`

Here's the problematic snippet:

```
fit_mc5 <- fitHigherOrder(text_tlp, 5)
create_me_mc5 <- function(num = 5, first_word = "i", n = 2) {
  for (i in 1:num) {
    set.seed(i+5)
    markovchainSequence(n = n, # generate 2 additional random words
                        markovchain = fit_mc5$Q,
                        t0 = tolower(first_word), include.t0 = T) %>% 
      # joint words
      paste(collapse = " ") %>% # join generated words with space
      # create proper sentence form
      str_replace_all(pattern = " ,", replacement = ",") %>% 
      str_replace_all(pattern = " [.]", replacement = ".") %>% 
      str_replace_all(pattern = " [!]", replacement = "!") %>% 
      str_to_sentence() %>% # start every sentences with capitalization
      print()
  }
}
    
    create_me_mc5(num = 1, first_word = "i", n = 10)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': no applicable method for `@` applied to an object of class "list"
```

I believe that this code results in an error because the `markovchainSequence` function does not recognize the `fit_mc5$Q` object as a valid Markov chain object, instead reading it as a list.

```
> class(fit_markov$estimate)
[1] "markovchain"
attr(,"package")
[1] "markovchain"
> class(fit_mc5$Q)
[1] "list"
```

I want to coerce or convert the output of the `fitHigherOrder` function to the `markovchain` class so that I can pass it to the `markovchainSequence function in custom function 'create_me_mc5.`

How can I accomplish this?

Ref 1: https://rpubs.com/nabiilahardini/text-generator

Ref 2: https://amr.isi.edu/download/amr-bank-v1.6.txt